# A possibility of removing excessive code when dynamically creating objects?

Tags: vb.net, object, dynamic, simplify

Wanted to know if there was a shorter way of writing what I'm currently writing when dynamically creating form objects.

Code below:

```
' Margins & width for buttons
        Dim distanceX As Integer = left + 20
        Dim distanceY As Integer = 120
        Dim btnWidth As Integer = 120

        ' Initializing buttons
        removeUndBtn = New Button
        numbBtn = New Button
        capsBtn = New Button
        subsBtn = New Button
        addTagsBtn = New Button
        previewBtn = New Button
        applyBtn = New Button
        cancelBtn = New Button

        ' Settings for buttons
        With removeUndBtn
            .Text = "Remove Underscore"
            .Visible = True
            .Enabled = False
            .Top = distanceY
            .Width = btnWidth
            .Left = distanceX
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf removeUndAction
        End With
        With numbBtn
            .Text = "Number songs"
            .Visible = True
            .Enabled = False
            .Top = removeUndBtn.Top + 22
            .Width = btnWidth
            .Left = distanceX
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf numbAction
        End With
        With capsBtn
            .Text = "Capitalization"
            .Visible = True
            .Top = numbBtn.Top + 22
            .Width = btnWidth
            .Left = distanceX
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf capsAction
        End With
        With subsBtn
            .Text = "Substitution"
            .Visible = True
            .Enabled = False
            .Top = capsBtn.Top + 22
            .Width = btnWidth
            .Left = distanceX
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf subsAction
        End With
        With addTagsBtn
            .Text = "Add tags"
            .Visible = True
            .Top = subsBtn.Top + 22
            .Width = btnWidth
            .Left = distanceX
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf addTagsAction
        End With
        With previewBtn
            .Text = "Preview"
            .Visible = True
            .Enabled = False
            .Top = addTagsBtn.Top + 44
            .Width = btnWidth
            .Left = distanceX
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf previewAction
        End With
        With applyBtn
            .Text = "Apply"
            .Visible = True
            .Top = previewBtn.Top + 22
            .Width = btnWidth
            .Left = distanceX
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf applyAction
        End With
        With cancelBtn
            .Text = "Cancel"
            .Visible = True
            .Top = applyBtn.Top + 22
            .Width = btnWidth
            .Left = distanceX
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf cancelAction
        End With

        ' Adding buttons to form
        Me.Controls.Add(removeUndBtn)
        Me.Controls.Add(numbBtn)
        Me.Controls.Add(capsBtn)
        Me.Controls.Add(subsBtn)
        Me.Controls.Add(addTagsBtn)
        Me.Controls.Add(previewBtn)
        Me.Controls.Add(applyBtn)
        Me.Controls.Add(cancelBtn)
```

The buttons in the above code are created dynamically because an indefinite number of objects not seen in the above code are created, expanding the size of the form.

Tips on particular variables that the values i'm setting are set like that by default, making multiple monotonous lines into one clean simple line. Anything like that is what I'm looking for.

Also, some of the buttons have Enabled set to false as their processes have not been completed.

Comment: For me your code haven`t "dynamic" values. Location of generated controls are same in relation of other dynamic controls. So based on this information I think maybe `UserControl` can be one approach.

Comment: Yes, sets of them on a user control, or code which makes one set work with/on different objects.  Since all `Preview`s will hook to the same handler, why does there need to be many of them?

Comment: @Fabio thanks for a tip! :)